# annotating local variables or method parameters

Tags: java, variables, annotations, metaprogramming

According to the class [ElementType](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#PARAMETER) in the API, you can annotate local variables and method parameters.

How is that done?

Comment: remember that "An annotation on a local variable declaration is never
retained in the binary representation."

Comment: @IAdapter Not even with `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just the usual way:

```
void method(@SomeAttr int param){
    @SomeAttr 
    int local = param * 2;
}
```